# ode failing to run - DINTDY- T (=R1) illegal

Tags: r, ode

```
result from ODE 
DINTDY-  T (=R1) illegal      
In above message, R1 = 16
 
      T not in interval TCUR - HU (= R1) to TCUR (=R2)      
In above message, R1 = 15.9441, R2 = 15.9441
 
DINTDY-  T (=R1) illegal      
In above message, R1 = 17
 
      T not in interval TCUR - HU (= R1) to TCUR (=R2)      
In above message, R1 = 15.9441, R2 = 15.9441
 
DLSODA-  Trouble in DINTDY.  ITASK = I1, TOUT = R1
In above message, I1 = 1
 
In above message, R1 = 17
```

I've tried to change the starting values and duration of the simulation but those don't seem to be working. I've also tried to debug the ode by running it for a single timestep but no luck.

## load relevant packages

library(deSolve)

```
# C = coral, measured as the biomass of a single head
# D = damselfish, a fish that dwells inside the coral, eats plankton, and
#     fertilizes the coral with its waste products
# H = hawkfish, a fish that dwells on the outside of the coral, is an
#     aggressive predator and can competitively displace P
# U = uberpredator, a fish that lives outside the coral and preys upon both
#     P and H
```

## Parameters and their definitions

```
params<- c(
  # CORAL:
  g_0 = 0.1, #fertilization-enhancement to coral growth rate
  g_1 = 1, #base growth rate of coral
  #n_D = .02,     # Excretion rate of damselfish
  #n_H = .005, # Excretion rate of hawkfish
  #h_N = 10*n_D,   # Half-saturation of excretion
  #nu = n_H/n_D,  # Scaling of hawkfish benefits relative to damselfish
  #eta = h_N/n_D,  # Scaling of half-saturation to damselfish
  m = .01, #mortality of coral
  
  # DAMSELFISH:
  r_D = .3, # base growth rate of planktivore
  k_D = 1, #carrying capacity per unit coral biomass of damselfish
  #exp_D = 1, #how carrying capacity of damselfish scales with coral size 
  alpha_DH = 2, # competitive effects of damselfish on hawkfish
  a_D = 0, #attack rate of uberpredator on damselfish
  
  # HAWKFISH
  r_H = .2, #base growth rate of hawkfish
  k_H = 1, #carrying capacity per unit coral surface area of hawkfish
  #exp_H = 1, #how carrying capcity of the hawkfish scales with coral size
  alpha_HD = .1, #competitive effects of hawkfish on planktivore
  a_H = .15 #attack rate of uberpredator on hawkfish
)


#this model has no uberpredator 

cmod <- function(t,y,params)
{
  C <- y[1] #coral biomass
  D <- y[2] #damselfish biomass
  H <- y[3] #hawkfish biomass
  
with(as.list(params), {
  
  # modified for saturating growth rate and density dependence:
  dCdt = C*(g_1*(D+H)+g_0-m)
  
  #Second equation: Damselfish biomass
  dDdt = r_D*D*(k_D*C-D-alpha_HD*H)/(k_D*C)-a_D*D
        
  #Third equation: Hawkfish biomass
  dHdt = r_H*H*(k_H*C-H-alpha_DH*D)/(k_H*C)-a_H*H
  
  return(list(c(dCdt,dDdt,dHdt)))
})
}

#simulation details
t <- seq(0,10000,by=1) #duration of simulation 
N.init <- c(C=1,D=2,H=2)

sim1 <- ode(N.init,t,cmod,params)
```

i expected a list of results for the focal parameters C,H,D

Comment: Can you check your model and parameters? There is a hyperexponential blow-up at `t=15.944122...` in the `C` component, there are no time steps that go further and thus no possibility to interpolate values at `t=16,17,...`. However already at time `t=1.27462169545` the computed values `[C,D,H]=[134.4961397,    2.47760126,   1.58399192] ` seem non-sensible. The values detoriate quickly, at `t=2.01082843748` one gets `[C,D,H]= [3.61471281e+03, 3.08565920e+00, 1.63965295e+00]` and so on.

Comment: fwiw i figured it out where i didn't have density affecting mortality in the coral equation so it was growing like bananas